# Printing a Path to a Leaf in an AVL Tree

Tags: python-3.x, avl-tree

I am trying to print the path to every single leaf in this AVL Tree. My question is: why does the program spit out the memory locations and file names of the element instead of the element?

```
from BinaryTree import BinaryTree
from BinaryTree import TreeNode

class AVLTree(BinaryTree):
    def __init__(self):
        BinaryTree.__init__(self)

    # Override the createNewNode method to create an AVLTreeNode
    def createNewNode(self, e):
        return AVLTreeNode(e)
    def getPath(self, o):
        path = BinaryTree.path(self, o);
        return path


    # Override the insert method to balance the tree if necessary 
    def insert(self, o):
        successful = BinaryTree.insert(self, o)
        if not successful:
            return False # o is already in the tree
        else:
            self.balancePath(o) # Balance from o to the root if necessary

        return True # o is inserted

    # Update the height of a specified node 
    def updateHeight(self, node):
        if node.left == None and node.right == None: # node is a leaf
            node.height = 0
        elif node.left == None: # node has no left subtree
            node.height = 1 + (node.right).height
        elif node.right == None: # node has no right subtree
            node.height = 1 + (node.left).height
        else:
            node.height = 1 + max((node.right).height, (node.left).height)

    # Balance the nodes in the path from the specified
    # node to the root if necessary
    def balancePath(self, o):
        path = BinaryTree.path(self, o)
        for i in range(len(path) - 1, -1, -1): 
            A = path[i]
            self.updateHeight(A)
            parentOfA = None if (A == self.root) else path[i - 1]

            if self.balanceFactor(A) == -2:
                if self.balanceFactor(A.left) <= 0:
                    self.balanceLL(A, parentOfA) # Perform LL rotation
                else:
                    self.balanceLR(A, parentOfA) # Perform LR rotation
            elif self.balanceFactor(A) == +2:
                if self.balanceFactor(A.right) >= 0:
                    self.balanceRR(A, parentOfA) # Perform RR rotation
                else:
                    self.balanceRL(A, parentOfA) # Perform RL rotation

    # Return the balance factor of the node
    def balanceFactor(self, node):
        if node.right == None: # node has no right subtree
            return -node.height
        elif node.left == None: # node has no left subtree
            return +node.height
        else:
            return (node.right).height - (node.left).height

    # Balance LL (see Figure 14.2) 
    def balanceLL(self, A, parentOfA):
        B = A.left # A is left-heavy and B is left-heavy

        if A == self.root:
            self.root = B
        else:
            if parentOfA.left == A:
                parentOfA.left = B
            else:
                parentOfA.right = B

        A.left = B.right # Make T2 the left subtree of A
        B.right = A # Make A the left child of B
        self.updateHeight(A)
        self.updateHeight(B)
    def getSearch(self, o):
        return BinaryTree.search(self, o)

    # Balance LR (see Figure 14.2(c)) 
    def balanceLR(self, A, parentOfA):
        B = A.left # A is left-heavy
        C = B.right # B is right-heavy

        if A == self.root:
            self.root = C
        else:
            if parentOfA.left == A:
                parentOfA.left = C
            else:
                parentOfA.right = C

        A.left = C.right # Make T3 the left subtree of A
        B.right = C.left # Make T2 the right subtree of B
        C.left = B
        C.right = A

        # Adjust heights
        self.updateHeight(A)
        self.updateHeight(B)
        self.updateHeight(C)

    # Balance RR (see Figure 14.2(b)) 
    def balanceRR(self, A, parentOfA):
        B = A.right # A is right-heavy and B is right-heavy

        if A == self.root:
            self.root = B
        else:
            if parentOfA.left == A:
                parentOfA.left = B
            else:
                parentOfA.right = B

        A.right = B.left # Make T2 the right subtree of A
        B.left = A
        self.updateHeight(A)
        self.updateHeight(B)

    # Balance RL (see Figure 14.2(d)) 
    def balanceRL(self, A, parentOfA):
        B = A.right # A is right-heavy
        C = B.left # B is left-heavy

        if A == self.root:
            self.root = C
        else:
            if parentOfA.left == A:
                parentOfA.left = C
            else:
                parentOfA.right = C

        A.right = C.left # Make T2 the right subtree of A
        B.left = C.right # Make T3 the left subtree of B
        C.left = A
        C.right = B

        # Adjust heights
        self.updateHeight(A)
        self.updateHeight(B)
        self.updateHeight(C)

    # Delete an element from the binary tree.
    # Return True if the element is deleted successfully
    # Return False if the element is not in the tree 
    def delete(self, element):
        if self.root == None:
            return False # Element is not in the tree

        # Locate the node to be deleted and also locate its parent node
        parent = None
        current = self.root
        while current != None:
            if element < current.element:
                parent = current
                current = current.left
            elif element > current.element:
                parent = current
                current = current.right
            else:
                break # Element is in the tree pointed by current

        if current == None:
            return False # Element is not in the tree

        # Case 1: current has no left children (See Figure 23.6)
        if current.left == None:
            # Connect the parent with the right child of the current node
            if parent == None:
                root = current.right
            else:
                if element < parent.element:
                    parent.left = current.right
                else:
                    parent.right = current.right

            # Balance the tree if necessary
            self.balancePath(parent.element)
        else:
            # Case 2: The current node has a left child
            # Locate the rightmost node in the left subtree of
            # the current node and also its parent
            parentOfRightMost = current
            rightMost = current.left

            while rightMost.right != None:
                parentOfRightMost = rightMost
                rightMost = rightMost.right # Keep going to the right

            # Replace the element in current by the element in rightMost
            current.element = rightMost.element

            # Eliminate rightmost node
            if parentOfRightMost.right == rightMost:
                parentOfRightMost.right = rightMost.left
            else:
                # Special case: parentOfRightMost is current
                parentOfRightMost.left = rightMost.left

            # Balance the tree if necessary
            self.balancePath(parentOfRightMost.element)

        self.size -= 1 # One element deleted
        return True # Element inserted
    def getLeafNodes(self):
        return BinaryTree.leafNodes(self)

# AVLTreeNode is TreeNode plus height 
class AVLTreeNode(TreeNode):
    def __init__(self, e):
        self.height = 0 # New data field
        TreeNode.__init__(self, e)
```

this is the binary tree it calls

```
class BinaryTree:
    def __init__(self):
        self.counter = -1
        self.root = None
        self.size = 0

    # Return True if the element is in the tree 
    def search(self, e):
        current = self.root # Start from the root

        while current != None:
            if e < current.element:
                current = current.left
            elif e > current.element:
                current = current.right
            else: # element matches current.element
                return True # Element is found

        return False
    def __iter__(self):
        return self


    def __next__(self):
        x = self.inorder()
        self.num = []
        for i in range(x.getSize()):
            self.num.append(x.pop())
        self.num.reverse()
        while True:
            self.counter += 1
            break
        return self.num[self.counter]

    # Insert element e into the binary search tree
    # Return True if the element is inserted successfully 
    def insert(self, e):
        if self.root == None:
            self.root = self.createNewNode(e) # Create a new root
        else:
            # Locate the parent node
            parent = None
            current = self.root
            while current != None:
                if e < current.element:
                    parent = current
                    current = current.left
                elif e > current.element:
                    parent = current
                    current = current.right
                else:
                    return False # Duplicate node not inserted

            # Create the new node and attach it to the parent node
            if e < parent.element:
                parent.left = self.createNewNode(e)
            else:
                parent.right = self.createNewNode(e)

        self.size += 1 # Increase tree size
        return True # Element inserted

    # Create a new TreeNode for element e
    def createNewNode(self, e):
        return TreeNode(e)

    # Return the size of the tree
    def getSize(self):
        return self.size

    # Inorder traversal from the root
    def inorder(self):
        self.inorderHelper(self.root)

    # Inorder traversal from a subtree 
    def inorderHelper(self, r):
        if r != None:
            self.inorderHelper(r.left)
            print(r.element, end = " ")
            self.inorderHelper(r.right)

    # Postorder traversal from the root 
    def postorder(self):
        self.postorderHelper(self.root)

    # Postorder traversal from a subtree 
    def postorderHelper(self, root):
        if root != None:
            self.postorderHelper(root.left)
            self.postorderHelper(root.right)
            print(root.element, end = " ")

    # Preorder traversal from the root 
    def preorder(self):
        self.preorderHelper(self.root)

    # Preorder traversal from a subtree 
    def preorderHelper(self, root):
        if root != None:
            print(root.element, end = " ")
            self.preorderHelper(root.left)
            self.preorderHelper(root.right)

    # Returns a path from the root leading to the specified element 
    def path(self, e):
        path = []
        current = self.root # Start from the root

        while current != None:
            path.append(current) # Add the node to the list
            if e < current.element:
                current = current.left
            elif e > current.element:
                current = current.right
            else:
                break
        return path # Return an array of nodes

    # Delete an element from the binary search tree.
    # Return True if the element is deleted successfully
    # Return False if the element is not in the tree 
    def delete(self, e):
        # Locate the node to be deleted and its parent node
        parent = None
        current = self.root
        while current != None:
            if e < current.element:
                parent = current
                current = current.left
            elif e > current.element: 
                parent = current
                current = current.right
            else:
                break # Element is in the tree pointed by current

        if current == None:
            return False # Element is not in the tree

        # Case 1: current has no left children
        if current.left == None:
            # Connect the parent with the right child of the current node
            if parent == None:
                self.root = current.right
            else:
                if e < parent.element:
                    parent.left = current.right
                else:
                    parent.right = current.right
        else:
            # Case 2: The current node has a left child
            # Locate the rightmost node in the left subtree of
            # the current node and also its parent
            parentOfRightMost = current
            rightMost = current.left

            while rightMost.right != None:
                parentOfRightMost = rightMost
                rightMost = rightMost.right # Keep going to the right

            # Replace the element in current by the element in rightMost
            current.element = rightMost.element

            # Eliminate rightmost node
            if parentOfRightMost.right == rightMost:
                parentOfRightMost.right = rightMost.left
            else:
                # Special case: parentOfRightMost == current
                parentOfRightMost.left = rightMost.left     

        self.size -= 1
        return True # Element deleted
    def leafNodes(self):
        self.leaves = []
        return self.leafNodesHelper(self.root)
    def leafNodesHelper(self, root):
        if root != None:
            if root.left == None and root.right == None:
                self.leaves.append(root.element)
            else:
                self.leafNodesHelper(root.left)
                self.leafNodesHelper(root.right)
        return self.leaves

    # Return true if the tree is empty
    def isEmpty(self):
        return self.size == 0

    # Remove all elements from the tree
    def clear(self):
        self.root == None
        self.size == 0

    # Return the root of the tree
    def getRoot(self):
        return self.root

class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self, e):
        self.element = e
        self.left = None  # Point to the left node, default None
        self.right = None # Point to the right node, default None
```

this is the test program that is frustrating me

```
from AVLTree20_3 import AVLTree

tree = AVLTree()

for i in range(1, 101):
    tree.insert(i)
x = tree.getLeafNodes()
for i in range(len(x)):
    path = tree.getPath(x[i])
    print(path)
```

Please help me figure out why this won't work. I have tried a debugger and printing from all three files but none seem to print out properly why is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that the path method returns a list of nodes.
have two solutions define the 1st override method (str) in the node class.
Or cross it as follows:

```
from AVLTree20_3 import AVLTree

tree = AVLTree()

for i in range(1, 101):
 tree.insert(i)
x = tree.getLeafNodes()

for i in range(len(x)):
 path = [x.element for x in tree.getPath(x[i])]
 print(path,"\n---------------------")
```